# Bake Subframe Animation

Tags: python, animation

I am trying to bake subframe animation data from a control rig to shape keys.
Here is my current approach:

```py
        for fr in all_frames:
            frame = int(fr // 1)
            subframe = fr % 1
            context.scene.frame_set(frame=frame, subframe=subframe)
            for d in shapekeys.animation_data.drivers:
                shapekeys.keyframe_insert(d.data_path)
```

Unfortunately, the keyframe_insert method discards the subframe component.

Is there a way to bake to subframes or is this a limitation of Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve this for now. While it's not possible bake to subframes directly (afaik), it is possible to use the `path_resolve` function to get the *evaluated* value. Using this method, I was able to keep all details on subframes.

```py
        # store the animation data per driver {data_path : [(fr, value),...]}
        anim_data_dict = {}
        for fr in all_frames:
            frame = int(fr // 1)
            subframe = fr % 1
            context.scene.frame_set(frame=frame, subframe=subframe)
            for d in shapekeys.animation_data.drivers:
                anim_data_dict.setdefault(d.data_path, []).append((fr, shapekeys.path_resolve(d.data_path)))
```